# How to prove this map is differentiable

Tags: banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra and $f: Inv(A) \to A$ be the map $a \mapsto a^{-1}$. I'm trying to show that $f$ is differentiable. My idea is to show that the limit of $\delta \to 0$ of 
$$ {\|(a + \delta a)^{-1} - a^{-1}\| \over |\delta| \|a\|}$$
exists that is, is finite. I have now run out of ideas. Because I got stuck I showed instead that $f$ is continuous which was easy enough. I hoped to use it somehow to show that $f$ is also differentiable but no luck.

Please can someone explain to me how to show that 
$$ \lim_{\delta \to 0}{\|(a + \delta a)^{-1} - a^{-1}\| \over |\delta| \|a\|}$$ 
exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a \in \text{Inv}(A)$ let
$$
L_a:A\to A,\quad L_a(h)=-a^{-1}ha^{-1}.
$$
$L_a$ is obviously a linear continuous map, and for every $h \in A$ with $\|a^{-1}h\|<1$ we have
$$
(a+h)^{-1}=(I+a^{-1}h)^{-1}a^{-1}=[I+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n(a^{-1}h)^n]a^{-1}=a^{-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n(a^{-1}h)^na^{-1}.
$$
It follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
\|f(a+h)-f(a)+a^{-1}ha^{-1}\|&\le&\sum_{n=2}^\infty\|(a^{-1}h)^na^{-1}\|\\
&\le&\|a^{-1}\|\sum_{n=2}^\infty\|a^{-1}h\|^n\\
&=&\|a^{-1}\|\frac{\|a^{-1}h\|^2}{1-\|a^{-1}h\|}. 
\end{eqnarray}
Hence
$$
\frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)-L_a(h)\|}{\|h\|}\le\frac{\|a^{-1}\|^3\|h\|}{1-\|a^{-1}h\|},
$$
i.e. $f$ is differentiable and
$$
df_a(h)=-a^{-1}ha^{-1} \quad \forall a \in \text{Inv}(A),\ h \in A.
$$

Comment: Thanks, how did you come up with $L_a$?

Comment: $L_a(h)$ is the linear part in the expansion of $(a+h)^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, but why did you figure that the linear part of that expansion is the derivative of $a^{-1}$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the derivative of a map?

Comment: I thought the derivative of a map $f$ at a point $a$ was 
$$ \lim_{\delta \to 0} {f(a + \delta) - f(a) \over \delta}$$ in the real numbers but then this can be generalized, no?

Comment: For a map $f$ between two normed spaces $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ and $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$, the derivative of $f$ at $a \in X$ is a CONTINUOUS LINEAR MAP $L_a$ such that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)-L_a(h)\|_Y}{\|h\|_X}=0.$$